# Import specific data for Yahoo finance into Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I want to import specific data from a table from Yahoo finance to Google sheets.

So far, I have managed to import the table from Yahoo but the specific row e.g. float data

I have used this: `=IMPORTHTML("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="& $B$1&"+Key+Statistics","table", 2)`

This line select the stock symbol in my spreadsheet, then draws the table from Yahoo,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it by accessing that index, try:

- `=index(IMPORTHTML("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="& $B$1&"+Key+Statistics","table", 2), 4, 2)`

the [index function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) will basically get a single item when the output is a table.

Comment: Hi, the function is not working anymore, I'm using this: =index(IMPORTHTML("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/="&A2&"+Key+Statistics","table", 2), 4, 2)

Any idea, what this issue is? I've changed the figures on the formula but still does not work. The error states that URL not working.